# Check if period of date, is overlapping any of the given period in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, prototypejs

I have a module for sales-person, where they can add their own managers. These will be displayed in ag-grid on UI. To add managers I need to select the manager, period start date, and period end date for a given manager. But simultaneously I also need to check the period of each manager, that any of the manager's dates should not overlap each other, based on it there Status is being decided. There can be N number of managers to a salesperson, but there should be only one Active manager to each sales-person at a time.

I am currently facing an issue while comparing the dates of the current manager to each of the given managers in the array.

I decide the status based on the following code:

```
decideStatus(): string {
    let status = '';
    let currentDate = new Date();
    let fromDate = this.salesPersonForm.value.StartDate;
    let tillDate = this.salesPersonForm.value.EndDate;

    if(fromDate <= currentDate && (tillDate > currentDate || tillDate == null)) {
      return status = 'Active'
    } else if(fromDate > currentDate) {
      return status = 'Onhold'
    } else if(tillDate < currentDate) {
      return status = 'Inactive'
    }
  }
```

I have the following piece of code for the adding the manager to the grid.

```
addManagers(){
    if(this.salesPersonForm.value.SalesPerson) {
      if(this.salesPersonForm.value.StartDate) {
        if(this.salesPersonForm.value.EndDate == null || (this.salesPersonForm.value.EndDate > this.salesPersonForm.value.StartDate)) {
          let loggedInUser = userName;
          let manager = {
            Name: someName
            FromDate: this.salesPersonForm.value.StartDate 
            TillDate: this.salesPersonForm.value.EndDate 
            CreatedAt: new Date()
            CreatedBy: loggedInUser,
            Status: this.decideStatus()
          }
          this.managers.push(manager)
        } else {
          return;
        }
      } else {
        return;
      }
    } else {
      return
    }
    this.clear();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.agGridReference.assignData(this.managers)
    }, 200);
  }
```

Idle UseCase: M1 - 01/01/2020 to 31/06/2020 - InActive
M2 - 01/08/2020 to 31/12/2021 - InActive
M3 - 01/01/2022 to somefuturevalue - Active

If dates are in the future than the current date, it will be considered as on hold.

InValid case: M1 - 01/01/2020 to 31/06/2020 - InActive
M2 - 01/05/2020 to 28/02/2021 - InActive
M3 - 01/01/2021 to 30/05/2021 - InActive

Comment: Is your `decideStatus` method throwing errors? If it does - can you share those errors? Are the dates you compare of the same type?

Comment: @MishaMashina No decideStatus does not throw errors, and the dates are of the same type.

Comment: So somewhere in the `decideStatus` method you'd like to check if this new manager's interval is overlapping with already existing menagers' intervals? I guess overlapping only makes sense if new manager is of 'active' status and there's at least one manager already with such status?

Comment: @MishaMashina I think I can check the intervals in any of the methods. But what logic should be implemented for checking each period with multiple periods in the same array is I am not able to figure out. Overlapping is needed to check because of these periods there is a commission system working, regardless of status. But yes only one manager should be of 'Active' status at a single time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you're going to push new manager into `managers` array only if new manager's interval is not overlapping with any existing manager's interval. Thus the check needs to be made before your `this.managers.push(manager)` line, something like this:

- replacing `this.managers.push(manager)` with:
  `this.compareDates(manager);`
- adding these two methods:

```
compareDates(newM) {
    let overlaps = 0;
    this.managers.forEach(m => {
      if (
        // first case:
        // saved manager starts before FromDate
        // and finishes after FromDate
        // of new manager:
        (this.prepareDate(m.FromDate) <= this.prepareDate(newM.FromDate) &&
          this.prepareDate(m.TillDate) >= this.prepareDate(newM.FromDate)) ||
        // second case:
        // saved manager starts after FromDate
        // and before the TillDate
        // of new manager:
        (this.prepareDate(m.FromDate) >= this.prepareDate(newM.FromDate) &&
          this.prepareDate(m.FromDate) <= this.prepareDate(newM.TillDate))
      ) {
        overlaps++;
      }
    });
    if (overlaps == 0) {
      // no overlaps, so push this new manager and do whatever else needs to be done
      this.managers.push(newM);
      console.log('Welcome, new manager!');
    } 
    else {
      // there is at least 1 overlap, so do something else
      // like: return with error message  
      console.log("This manager's interval overlaps with interval(s) of " 
      + overlaps +' other manager(s)!'
      );
    }
  }
```

And the helper method to return timestamp of each date in the previous method:

```
prepareDate(date) {
    let parts = date.split('/');
    return Date.parse(parts[2] + '/' + parts[1] + '/' + parts[0]);
}
```

To see it in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j9ldef

Comment: Thank you for the idea to get along, regarding how to solve. It didn't exactly solve the problem but yes, it is helpful. Thanks a lot.